# wordpress - dynamically creating pages with templates in a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to create pages upon theme activation. It all works great when the page templates are in the root of the theme. however I am trying to reference my template files from within a 'page-templates' directory (root -> page-templates). What am I doing wrong?

```
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
    add_action('init', 'create_initial_pages');
}

function create_initial_pages() {    
$pages = array(
     // Page Title and URL (a blank space will end up becomeing a dash "-")
    'Services' => array(
        // Page Content     // Template to use (if left blank the default template will be used)
        'Services Content'=>'page-bottom-sidebar.php'),
);

foreach($pages as $page_url_title => $page_meta) {
        $id = get_page_by_title($page_url_title);

    foreach ($page_meta as $page_content=>$page_template){
    $page = array(
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_title'  => $page_url_title,
        'post_name'   => $page_url_title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_content' => $page_content,
        'post_parent' => ''
    );

    if(!isset($id->ID)){
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($page);
        if(!empty($page_template)){
                update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $page_template);
        }
    }
 }
};
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I know its something simple I just cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page template is in a subdirectory, you should include the subdirectory together with the template name when setting `_wp_page_template`.

So if your `page-bottom-sidebar.php` is in the `page-templates` directory of the theme, instead of:

```
'Services Content'=>'page-bottom-sidebar.php'
```

you would need to have:

```
'Services Content'=>'page-templates/page-bottom-sidebar.php'
```